# Cannot declare class App\User because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel

i've been trying to implement the spatie medialibrary laravel package into my project, but i'm getting a huge problem with this and i've been strugling, i don't know how to fix it, anyone has any idea about this problem?

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaConversions;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User implements HasMediaConversions
    {
    use Notifiable;
    use HasMediaTrait;
```

error i'm getting:

```
Cannot declare class App\User because the name is already in use
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User;` to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User as EloquentUser;`. That way it's aliased. 

As it is currently, `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User` makes `User` available in the `App` namespace so redeclaring a class with this name causes a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a different class | library with the same name:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User;
```

If you remove it or use an alias "as AliasName" it should work.